# How to Check if Multi Inputs have same Value with same Classes (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to apply validation in input to no to add the same value again.

```
<input type="text" data-loop="1" class="form-control Item_1 Item" name="Item">
<input type="text" data-loop="1" class="form-control Item_2 Item" name="Item">
<input type="text" data-loop="1" class="form-control Item_3 Item" name="Item">
```

Here is the jQuery to handle this.

```
$('.TableBody').on('change', '.Item', function() {
    var loop_id = $(this).data('loop');
    var Item = $('.Item_'+loop_id).closest('.Item').val();

    });
});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the input files and use the values as keys:

(Pseudo code)

```
lookup = {}
for each([item_number, value])) {
  if (lookup[value]) {
    throw error ('Items ' + item_number + ' and '  + lookup[value] + ' are identical')
  } else {
    lookup[value] = item_number
  }
```

}

Comment: Can you please explain it via dummy code. jQuery doesn't support Foreach